# How to add new items to the bottom of a ListView and remove old items from the top of it at the same time?

Tags: android, listview

I have a task that display thousands of items in a ListView. So I need to load the data of these items into memory. But the data of each item is bigger than 1KB, thus load all the data into memory will drain the memory and cause OOM exception. In fact, I load only a portion of those data at first and if the user scroll to the bottom of the ListView, more data will be added into the ListView. But if the user keep scrolling to the bottom, all the data will be loaded into memory at last, OOM appears.

In order to solve the problem, I think I can set a max limitation to the length of the ListView. For example, set the max length to 500. When the user keep scrolling to the bottom of the ListView, add 50 new items to the end of the ListView and remove 50 items from the top of it at the same time, thus the max length of the ListView keep the same. I know how to add new items to the end and remove old items from the top of the ListView, but when I trying to do this together, strange things happen, the content of the ListView is not what I expected.

So, anyone who knows how to solver my problem?

Any useful answer will be appreciated, but please don't ask me to change the data size of the item, because I don't have the right to do that.

The pseudo-code(The scrollListener is set to the ListView):

```
class MyOnScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{

     public void onScrollChange(View, int, int, int){
         if(reach the bottom){
            add50ItemsToTheBottomOfTheList();
            remove50FromTheTopOfTheList();
            myListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. Try this.

Comment: @Raghunandan I know this EndlessAdapter a little, but not clear whether it will load all the data into memory when the user keep scrolling to the bottom of the ListView?

Comment: why don't you post a different question regarding the same tagging commonsware and android. I am sure there are people who can help you out with endless scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remove some items from the top of a ListView, but this will cause strange behaviors to the ListView. So, I just set those items at the top of list to null, and load them from the network again when the user scroll back.